# How do I fix this hourly rate calculator?

Tags: python

Keep getting bad input errors on this python code. Can someone walk me through what I'm doing wrong? Thanks. The task is that the code works out time-and-a-half for the hourly rate for all hours worked above 40 hours. Using 45 hours and a rate of 10.50 per hour to test the program, the pay should then be 498.75. I keep getting 708.75...

```
hrs = input("Enter Hours:")
h = float(hrs)
rate = input("Enter Rate:")
r = float(rate)
double_r = r * 1.5

total = 0.0

if h <= 40.00:
    total = h * r  

elif h > 40.00: 
    total = h * double_r

print(total)
```

Comment: If it's bad input errors, then the problem is probably with the input not being convertible to float. You could replace `h` with `try: h=float(hrs) except: print('please input numbers')`

Comment: `BadInput` is not an error in Python. You will need to show the actual error

Comment: On the line `elif h => 40.00:`, `=>` isn't a valid operator. You probably meant `>=`

Comment: 10,5×1,5×45 = 708.75 so the program is exactly doing what you are asking..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't a coding problem but a math problem: You're multiplying every hour with the double_r rate (`45 * 10.5 * 1.5 = 708.75`). If you only want the hours above 40 hours to be multiplied with the higher rate then you have to multiply them extra (`40 * r` for the normal rate and `(h-40) * double_r` for the rest with the better rate. Your code should look like this:

```
if h <= 40.00:
    total =  h * r  

elif h > 40.00: 
    total = 40 * r + (h - 40) * double_r
```

Comment: Ah, can't believe I missed this. Thanks a lot, Benedikt!

Answer (score 2):

```
hrs = float(input("Enter Hours: "))
rate = float(input("Enter Rate: "))

double_rate = rate * 1.5

total = 0.0

if hrs <= 40.00:
    total = hrs * rate  

elif hrs > 40.00: 
    total = ((hrs - 40 ) * double_rate) + (40 * rate)

print(total)
```

Comment: hrs = float(input("Enter Hours:"))
rate = float(input("Enter Rate:"))
double_r = rate * 1.5

if hrs <= 40.00:
    total = hrs * rate

elif hrs > 40.00: 
    total = ((hrs-40) * double_r) + (40 * rate)
else:
  total = 0.0

print(total)

would be cleaner

Answer (score 1):

Is this bad input error or logical error ?
I don't have solution for first one, but I surely have it for the second part.

According to your code, If hours are <=40 , you are multiplying the hour with the rate.
but if it greater than 40, you are multiply the hour with the rate with 1.5 .
Here the logic is going wrong.
You just need to add the extra 1.5 for those hours which are greater than 40.

For that, you would have to modify your total statement.
Something like this :
total = ((h - 40 ) * double_r) + (40 * r)

So for 45 hours with 10.5 rate ,
it would be  40 * 10.5 =  420
and 5*10.5*1.5 = 78.75
thus resulting in 498.75

If this helps, please upvote. :)

Comment: Really helpful comment, Inder, thank you! it was bad input logic error and my math was definitely the flaw.